# How to change a certain windows setting using python?

Tags: python, windows, command, settings

I need to change this setting on/off using python:

'Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode'

I have looked over the internet and can't find any ways to change the settings - this can be via python or command line.

What I'd really need is something like:

```
hideTaskbar = True # Hides taskbar
hideTaskbar = False # Shows taskbar
```

Comment: It's probably a Windows registry setting. If you can determine where it is, you may be able to change its value from Python (assuming the script has admin privileges).

Answer (score 1):

1. You are able to do it with running a command that this [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/677619/how-to-hide-the-taskbar-on-windows-10/) explains

Hide

```
powershell -command "&{$p='HKCU:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3';$v=(Get-ItemProperty -Path $p).Settings;$v[8]=3;&Set-ItemProperty -Path $p -Name Settings -Value $v;&Stop-Process -f -ProcessName explorer}"
```

Show

```
powershell -command "&{$p='HKCU:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3';$v=(Get-ItemProperty -Path $p).Settings;$v[8]=2;&Set-ItemProperty -Path $p -Name Settings -Value $v;&Stop-Process -f -ProcessName explorer}"
```

2. You are able to run powersell command

```
import subprocess

showing = "&{$p='HKCU:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3';$v=(Get-ItemProperty -Path $p).Settings;$v[8]=2;&Set-ItemProperty -Path $p -Name Settings -Value $v;&Stop-Process -f -ProcessName explorer}"
hiding = "&{$p='HKCU:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3';$v=(Get-ItemProperty -Path $p).Settings;$v[8]=3;&Set-ItemProperty -Path $p -Name Settings -Value $v;&Stop-Process -f -ProcessName explorer}"
def run(cmd):
    subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", cmd])

run(hiding)

run(showing)
```